# Download test links are working in Brackets' live preview, but not when I test in dedicated browser window

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a site in Brackets and everything is working 100% how it should in live preview, including a button that downloads something. However, when I test the page in Edge or even a dedicated window in Chrome, it doesn't do anything. My live preview is in Chrome, ftr. Any idea why I'm not getting anything when I test outside of live preview? The download button relies on javascript files, if that helps. Javascript is enabled on all sites in my browser settings. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

please give more details about this issue
you didn't post the code behind your buttons.

most probably the problem related to your code in the download bottom indicating the wrong path for the file which you are downloading , the reason behind this working on your live preview browser that files are indicating correct path locally.

to find the exactly problem i would check the java error by pressing f12 on the browser when  i try outside the server .

if you could place the code on the button i will edit this post and give you better answer based on the details you provided .

good luck

Answer (score 0):

After checking the console log, it appears to be an issue with "Tainted Canvas" and local disk files, security, etc. I could set up a local web server for testing (and I will eventually) which should fix the problem, but for now, since its working in Brackets' live preview, I am going to assume everything is fine and I'll verify that all upon deployment.